# Vuetify don't apply default color, components are white

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

i am using Vuetify for my project.
The issue is that the default theme is white, or black with the props "black".

I checked this post: [Vuetify: colors are not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50003226/vuetify-colors-are-not-showing-up)
Even when i put my components code in the v-app, it's still black.

I didn't change anything, i think ?

I use router-vue.

[image]

Below is my code:
App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss"></style>
```

My component:

```
<template>
  <v-card max-width="400">
    <v-app-bar dark>
      <v-toolbar-title>Formulaire de connexion</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-col>
      <v-form v-model="valid" lazy-validation ref="form">
        <v-row>
          <v-text-field
            :rules="rulesLogin"
            label="Identifiant"
            v-model="identifiant"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <v-text-field
            :rules="rulesLogin"
            type="password"
            label="Mot de passe"
            v-model="motDePasse"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <v-btn color="primary" dark @click="seConnecter">Se connecter</v-btn>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <v-btn color="primary" dark>Mot de passe oublié ?</v-btn>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <v-btn color="primary" dark>Pas de compte ? Créer un compte</v-btn>
        </v-row>
      </v-form>
    </v-col>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
import service from "@/services/login.services";
export default {
  name: "LoginForm",
  data() {
    return {
      valid: true,
      identifiant: "",
      motDePasse: ""
    };
  },
  computed: {
    rulesLogin() {
      return [v => !!v || "Ce champ est obligatoire"];
    }
  },
  methods: {
    seConnecter() {
      if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
        const params = {
          identifiant: this.identifiant,
          motDePasse: this.motDePasse
        };
        service.connexion(params);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

plugins/vuetify.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({});
```

main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import "./registerServiceWorker";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Thanks =)

Comment: are you trying to activate vuetify dark theme instead of white or something else?

Comment: Not at all, i just want to use the basic vuetify for now

Comment: dark is a property predefined for components to invert the applied colors. It works as expected. What are you trying to achieve specifically?

Comment: Even if i put the props color at blue, red or w/e color, it remains white.

Comment: remove dark prop and define text color in class like that: class="blue yellow--text"

Comment: Tried, remain the same =/